# Muirhead proof $\implies$ AM-GM proof

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It is a common sentiment among people involved with maths Olympiads that Muirhead's inequality should only be used to find if an AM-GM proof exists.

> A common bruteforce technique with inequalities is to clear denominators, multiply everything out, and apply Muirhead's or Schur's. However, it is worth noting that any inequality that can be proved directly with Muirhead can also be proved using the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean inequality. In fact, IMO gold medalist Thomas Mildorf says it is unwise to use Muirhead in an Olympiad solution; one should use an application of AM-GM instead. Thus, it is suggested that Muirhead be used only to verify that an inequality can be proved with AM-GM before demonstrating the full AM-GM proof.

My question is: Can that fact guide us in finding that AM-GM proof? Other than the fact that it implies its existance.

I was trying to solve $\displaystyle a+b+c \leq \frac{a^3}{bc}+\frac{b^3}{ac}+\frac{c^3}{ab}$. By clearing denominators $\displaystyle a^2bc+ab^2c+abc^2\leq a^4+b^4+c^4$ we can get a proof by Muirhead's since $(2,1,1)\prec (4,0,0)$. But I had a harder time finding that AM-GM proof $\displaystyle \sum a^2 bc=\sum (a^3)^{2/3}(b^3)^{1/3}(c^3)^{1/3}\leq \sum 2a^3/3+b^3/3+c^3/3$. I used this example as a reference if needed.

Could the Muirhead solution guide you to how you should apply AM-GM on the cleared denominators? Maybe by the weighted AM-GM? Or does the fact that a Muirhead proof exists just mean that you should randomly look for the AM-GM proof either on the initial inequality or its cleared denominators version or even an intermediate step without giving you any further indication on how to apply it?

Comment: You can use Muirhead in math Olympiad without proof. This considered known as AM-GM, Holder, C-S, Rearrangement and more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From weighted AM-GM, we get
$$
   \frac12 a^4 + \frac14 b^4 + \frac14 c^4 \ge (a^4)^{1/2} (b^4)^{1/4} (c^4)^{1/4} = a^2bc.
$$
If we add up the symmetric versions of this inequality, we get exactly the inequality $$a^4 + b^4 + c^4 \ge a^2 bc + a b^2 c + a b c^2.$$

In general, whenever one exponent sequence majorizes another, we can somehow group up the terms of Muirhead's inequality and apply AM-GM several times, instead.

The grouping is not immediate, and often it is not unique. To give another example: suppose we applied Muirhead's inequality to get  $$a^3b + a^3c + b^3a + b^3c + c^3a + c^3b \ge 2a^2 bc + 2a b^2 c + 2a b c^2.$$
To deduce the same inequality with AM-GM, the term $a^2bc$ must somehow be written as $$(a^3b)^{n_1} (a^3c)^{n_2} (b^3a)^{n_3} (b^3c)^{n_4} (c^3a)^{n_5} (c^3b)^{n_6}$$ where $n_1 + n_2 + n_3 + n_4 + n_5 + n_6 = 1$. This is underconstrained. For example, we can say $$\frac14 a^3 b + \frac14 a^3 c + \frac14 b^3a + \frac14 c^3 a \ge (a^3b)^{1/4} (a^3c)^{1/4} (b^3a)^{1/4} (c^3a)^{1/4} = a^2bc$$ or we can say $$\frac13 a^3b + \frac13 a^3c + \frac16 b^3c + \frac16 c^3b \ge (a^3b)^{1/3} (a^3c)^{1/3} (b^3c)^{1/6}(c^3b)^{1/6} = a^2bc.$$
For help coming up with these: I first figured that we'd need to use the $a^3b$ and/or the $a^3c$ terms to get a factor $a^2$ on the right. Since $a^2bc$ has equal exponents of $b$ and $c$, I decided we might as well treat $b$ and $c$ in the same way on the left. This is still underconstrained, so to simplify our lives, I threw some terms away to get a unique solution - in two different ways.

Whichever way we use AM-GM, once we add up all symmetric versions of the inequality, we should get the same inequality that Muirhead had.

A proof of Muirhead's inequality can be used to "chase down" one particular construction of the exponents used in weighted AM-GM, but it's probably not worth it.

Comment: This was very insightful. It also raises another question that has been on mind for a while now and it is about the direction in which we are proving things i.e., say we want to prove $A\geq B$, one way to consider $A$ and find upper bounds until we prove $A\geq B$ or we could find lower bounds for $B$. How should I go about picking which of these two ways to use? Something I came to accept was that I'd work with the side that was more "complicated" in the sense that $a^2bc$ is more complicated than $a^4$ and that's why I opted to do my proof as such. But it seems like you chose $a^4$, why?

Comment: My logic was just that the inequality AM-GM generates is always going to have several terms on the AM (upper bound) side and a single term on the GM (lower bound) side. Therefore each of $a^2bc$, $ab^2c$, and $abc^2$ is fated to be a geometric mean, and we work out how to combine multiples of $a^4$, $b^4$, or $c^4$ to get an arithmetic mean to match. I didn't really think of it as a decision between finding an upper bound or lower bound on any particular side of the inequality.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov I think for the inequality $\sum\limits_{sys}a^3b^2\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}a^3bc$ your reasoning does not help: The inequality is true by Muidhead, but you can't prove it by using  weighted AM-GM like your first example. Does not exist non-negatives $x$, $y$ and $z$ with sum $1$, for which $xa^3b^2+yb^3c^2+zc^3a^2\geq a^3bc$

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg If the sum on the left is a symmetric sum, then it includes both $a^3b^2$ and $a^3 c^2$ as terms, and their geometric mean is $a^3bc$. If not, then I don't think the inequality $a^3b^2 + b^3c^2 + c^3a^2 \ge a^3bc + ab^3c + abc^3$ is true.

Comment: (For example, set $a=1$, $b=2$, and $c$ large; the dominant term on the left is $c^3$ and the dominant term on the right is $2c^3$.)

Comment: @Misha Lavrov Yes, the last inequality is wrong.  It says that you can't prove $\sum\limits_{sym}a^3b^2\geq\sum\limits_{sym}a^3bc$ by weighted AM-GM as in  your first example.

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can. Add up all $6$ permutations of $\frac12 a^3 b^2 + \frac12 a^3 c^2 \ge a^3 bc$.

Comment: @Misha Lavrov In your first example it was not exactly so.

Answer (score 3):

Finding an answer by weighted AM-GM and Muirhead is very directly linked, though it may not simplify the work needed in practice, you'll have to solve a set of simultaneous linear equations in either case.  Majorisation $x \succ y$ (ie. Muirhead) is equivalent to $y$ being a convex combination of $x$ and its permutations.  Using your example, this means:
$$(4,0,0) \succ (2, 1, 1) \iff w_1(4,0,0)+w_2(0, 4, 0)+w_3(0, 0, 4)=(2, 1, 1)$$
for some non-negative weights $w_i$ s.t. $\sum_i w_i=1$.  In fact finding these $w_i$ will give you AM-GM coefficients to use immediately. In this case, it is easily seen the weights $w = (\frac12, \frac14, \frac14)$ does the job, so on cyclically summing
$$\frac12a^4+\frac14b^4+\frac14c^4 \geqslant a^2bc$$
you get an equivalent AM-GM proof.